Invalid product archive metadata when uploading electron app to Mac App Store using Transporter
I am getting these error when uploading an electron app to Mac App Store using transporter.
Asset validation failed (90230)
Invalid product archive metadata. Error in keyPath [product-metadata.product-identifier]. Please re-build your archive with an up-to-date version of Xcode, and submit again. (ID: 42de3de7-0fab-4f22-ab01-06195842aaaa)

Asset validation failed (90230)
Invalid product archive metadata. Error in keyPath [product-metadata.product-version]. Please re-build your archive with an up-to-date version of Xcode, and submit again. (ID: 63470cc8-c192-4500-a51d-ded305887f88)

I am using electron forge (7.3.1), updated to latest version of electron (29.1.6) and XCode(15.3), used packagerConfig.extendInfo to overwrite the following keys and checked the final package does have these in info.plist
  <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
  <string>14.4</string>
  <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
  <string>23E208</string>
  <key>DTXcode</key>
  <string>1530</string>
  <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
  <string>15E204a</string>

Where is product-metadata defined and how do I fix it?

Turns out it refers to the arguments of productbuild
     --identifier product-identifier
         The given unique (non-localized) product-identifier will be associated with the product.

     --version product-version
         The given product-version string will be associated with the product.

I have to modify @electron/osx-sign to include these arguments for the productbuild command

productbuild requires you to use the --component variation of its command line options when building for the App Store. This is made explicit in https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/productbuild/. If you use the other variations, you get a valid .pkg file but the app verification via transporter or altool will give you the warnings in the posted question. This tripped us up for a while as we ported an app from independent distribution to be App Store compliant.
